# Using Classes to Remove Stopwords

Tags: python

Wondering if I can get a better understanding of how I can solve this problem. I have a class and a subclass and I wish to use them both.

```
class TextLook():
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.__text = text
  def setStopWords(self, words):
    ''' set stop words as recieved in the parameters '''
    stopWords = words.copy()
  def filteredText(self):
    ''' remove filter words from the text 
        return filtered text
    '''
    splitText = self.__text.split(" ")
    newText = [text for text in splitText if text.lower() not in stopWords]
    result = " ".join(newText)
    return result
class TextCheck(TextLook):
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.__text = text
  def getWordFrequency(self):
    ''' Call the filteredText() method
    '''
    editedWords = ta.filteredText()


ta = TextCheck("John had a car that had the roof of")
ta.setStopWords(["a", "the"])
ta.getWordFrequency()
```

I am creating the object "ta" to initialize in the TextCheck class. I then set the stop words and I believe it's stored in the stopWords? And for now, I just want to be able to split the string and store it in splitText. And then use the stopWords variable as a filter in the splitText with that list comprehension chunk.

The problem is I am baffled at why I keep getting an AttributeError for the splitText line:

```
AttributeError: 'TextCheck' object has no attribute '_TextLook__text'
```

Comment: Yes, *of course* because you are using double-underscore name-mangling. The only point of that is to avoid name collisions in subclasses.  Just don't use double-underscore name-mangling. As an aside, `setStopwords` doesn't store any attributes. It assigns to a local varialble, `stopWords` but that isn't available in other methods

Comment: Note, your class structure doesn't make sense. Why does `TextCheck` inherit from `TextLook`? But then, it just uses some global instance of `TextCheck`.

Comment: Hi Juanpa, thanks for the quick response. Yes, the double-underscore name thing fixed that portion with the AttributeError. Unfortunately, this is an assignment I am working on and I confined to how these methods and classes are laid out. So this is what I have written so far. The ta.setStopWords has to reference the TextLook in order to use the setStopWords method. As a result, I made TextCheck a subclass of TextLook.

Comment: The other issue I am coming across is that the stopWords variable isn't being stored so when the line for the list comprehension takes place, it states that stopWords aren't defined. So I'm guessing there's a problem with how I made the TextCheck subclass if it should even be a subclass?

Comment: "The ta.setStopWords has to reference the TextLook in order to use the setStopWords method. As a result, I made TextCheck a subclass of TextLook." I'm sorry, that fundamentally doesn't make any sense. You are just using a global reference to some instance that you create outside the class. This entirely misses the point of OOP, which is to *encapsulate* state. Ideally, you should be providing external requirments to you classes as arguments to the constructor. `TextCheck` could take a `TextLook` instance as an argument.

Comment: Yes, I already explained, you aren't using an attribute. You are simply assigning to a local variable. That variable ceases to exist when the function terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
class TextLook():
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.__text = text
  def setStopWords(self, words):
    ''' set stop words as recieved in the parameters '''
    self.stopWords = words.copy()
  def filteredText(self):
    ''' remove filter words from the text 
        return filtered text
    '''
    splitText = self.__text.split(" ")
    newText = [text for text in splitText if text.lower() not in self.stopWords]
    result = " ".join(newText)
    return result

class TextCheck(TextLook):
  def __init__(self, text):
    super().__init__(text)
    
  def getWordFrequency(self):
    ''' Call the filteredText() method
    '''
    editedWords = self.filteredText()
    return editedWords


ta = TextCheck("John had a car that had the roof of")
ta.setStopWords(["a", "the"])
ta.getWordFrequency()
```

Comment: `def __init__` just to call `super` is pointless, why have `TextCheck` inherit from `TextLook` anyway?

Comment: This line: `editedWords = ta.filteredText()` should reference `self` rather than `ta`.

Comment: In this case it might be. but in order to override functions of the parents class add new functionality to a class  without defining any new variables. You only need to call the constructor of the parent class using super.

Comment: @pavel, noted and corrected. Somehow it works with ta as well. Using objects directly in the class for referencing might become a problem if you instantiate multiple objects as self will reference the latest object and ta wont.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! That indeed solved the problem! Adding the "self" portion addressed the issues.